# Files in C, how to do input

Tags: c, file, file-io, input

This is my output function

```
void output(int n){

   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("sqrt.txt", "w");
   for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
       fprintf(fp, "%.2f\n", sqrt(i));
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```

I'm required to make an input function (it reads the output function) that prompts the user to enter the name of the file to be opened. I need the contents of the file to be printed. If it is an invalid file name, the program should exit.

How to start this exercise?

Comment: *"**If it is an invalid file name**, the program should exit **then the contents of the file is printed**."* - That is an impossible requirement.

Comment: @EdS. Try it now with my edits to clarify what I'm pretty sure he meant.

Answer (score 1):

To read a file in C, you use the `fopen` function almost just like what you had before, except passing it **`r`***ead* rather than **`w`***rite*. To read the file after it's been opened, you can use `fread` or `fscanf`. The file can be closed as usual with `fclose`.

If you want to read from the user rather than from a file, you can use `fread` with `stdin` instead of a file or (for the equivalent of `fscanf`) `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` return a pointer that can be null: if it is, that mean your process was not able to open the file. So you have to check the return value of `fopen` to know if the file exist (I am not sure, but if the file exist and the return value is NULL, that means you probably have not the necessary right).

Hope it can help.